# Get values to table according to 2 row values in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, loops, get, multiple-columns

i have table in database like this:

```
 name    date    year
 John    1/5/15  2015
 Maria   3/3/15  2015
 John    7/3/16  2016
 Steve   5/2/16  2016
 Steve   9/7/17  2017
 John    9/1/17  2017
```

And want to get table like this:

```
Name    2015    2016    2017
John    1/5/15  7/3/16  9/1/17
Maria   3/3/15
Steve           5/2/16  9/7/17
```

I tried with this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(name),date,year FROM table ORDER BY name ASC";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
```

Now I don't know what loop to use to get data to look like in second table.

I tried with this code

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
<td>" . $row["prezime_ime"] . "</td>
<td>" . ($row["date"]) . "</td>
```

Now I'm stuck here.
I'm new to PHP so please can anyone help me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I guess you have only one entry for name each year? do you know the years?

Comment: yes. only one name entry each year, yes I know the years

Answer (score 1):

You can do a group by

```
SELECT name,
       MAX( CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2015
                 THEN date
            END) as 2015,
       MAX( CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2016
                 THEN date
            END) as 2016,
       MAX( CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2017
                 THEN date
            END) as 2017
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: ok, I put that code to my query, but how to get that data to table cell

Comment: run the query on the db, you will get the exact result you request on your question.